# Change of variables to apply Melnikov method

Tags: chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

Supposing there is a system of non-autonomous non-linear differential equations with small damping and small forcing. The unperturbed system (zero damping and forcing) is Hamiltonian but neither has a saddle nor a homoclinic/heteroclinic loop in the phase space. As such, the [Melnikov method](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=melnikov+method) for detecting horseshoes is not applicable immediately. However, after a non-linear transformation of variables, the transformed system does have a homoclinic loop in the unperturbed phase space to which the Melnikov method can be applied. My question is: Is the resulting Melnikov function/curve valid for the original set of variables also?